# How to track origin of a ghost process in ubuntu that is causing postgres to take 100% of CPU usage in Amazon EC2 container?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, postgresql

I am running PostgreSQL 10.10 (Ubuntu 10.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) on an AWS EC2 micro instance. Previously, I had allowed remote connections to postgres db from anywhere. After some days, I am seeing an unknown process run by the `postgres` user is taking 100% of CPU usage. Running `top` command gives similar output.

```
8092 postgres  20   0  302872 266776      0 S 99.3 26.5   2574:21 WI0oUt
```

There is no active query that is running long in the background. I stopped the postgres DB, even then that ghost process is running. I got probable answer of the problem [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/920277/postgresql-is-out-of-control-high-cpu-load-high-memory-consumption). But I need to know which parent process is starting the execution of such ghost child processes? If I run `ps` with the `PID`, I get `PPID` as 1. I need to know what is the infected program that is running those child processes?

I already tried running `man`,`appros` for the processname, I tried resetting the `postgres` user password to tackle the compromise,but no effect. Anyway to find out which infected program is causing this? or how can I handle this situation without formatting the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s very hard to *un-compromise* a server. Best bet is to:

- **dump** your database (using `pg_dump`),
- **delete** the EC2 instance,
- **create** new instance,
- **reinstall** postgres, and
- **reload** the data.

**Lesson:** Never ever leave database servers open to the world. Use Security Group to restrict access only to the IPs that actually need access. And ideally use AWS RDS that can automatically patch your database to mitigate security issues.